# How to get sum of the values for every 10 rows?

Tags: vb.net

Have a column in Datagridview (over 300 rows) and would like to get the sum of every 10 rows. There is no gap between the data in Column 1.

I just want to have the sum value for every 10th rows in the other column. What I have tried showing me the cumulative #s in each row!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

C1  C2

2
3
4
6
5
3
5
7
6
5   46

8
9
4
7
5
2
1
2
5
4   47

1
2
6
.
.
.

```
Dim sum As integer = 0

For i = 0 To data1.Rows.Count - 1
sum += data1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
data1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = sum

If (i+1) = 10 Then
Sum = 0
Else
End If

Next
```

Comment: Are there actually gaps in the rows as your example shows, or is that just to show it?

Comment: Can you get the sum of the first 2 rows? That would be a good beginning. If you have this, can you show us the code?

Comment: no, there is no gap, just for show..! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, here is one example:

Loop over every row to sum, then on every 10th output sum and reset number.

```
    For i = 0 To data1.Rows.Count - 1
        sum += data1(0, i).Value
        If i.ToString.EndsWith("9") Then 'since it starts at 0, 10th ends with 9 not 0
            data1(1, i).Value = sum
            sum = 0
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much Drule for your help! appreciate it.

Comment: @Ako It is customary to thank someone by accepting there answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: The code worked good, but now I am running to different problem! when trying to use the calculated "sum" from Cell(1) to calculate another parameter, I am getting an error as" Converting from string to Double is not valid". is there any way that I can convert the sum in column 1 to double? thank.

Comment: @CruleD [DataGridCell.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_Value) is an Object so adding it to the Integer sum may have strange results. Try `Option Strict On` at the top of your code

Comment: @Ako put Cdbl infront, like this Cdbl(data1(0, i).Value). But all those values are integers, so you should use Cint.

Comment: adding Option Strict On will results of bunch of errors as , disallows implicit conversions from "Double to String"...... did put CDbl, didn't solve the issue? thanks.

Comment: @Ako "Double to String", at what line? The do whatever.ToString to convert that double to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to get the sum of each group of n rows

```
Private Function getSumsOfGroupsOfNRows(n As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Double)
    Return DataGridView1.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).
        GroupBy(Function(r) Math.Truncate(r.Index / n)).
        Select(Function(g) g.Sum(Function(r) CDbl(r.Cells(0).Value)))
End Function
```

Test it with this

```
Dim n = 10
' adds numbers 1 through 100 in the datagridview, for testing
DataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(
    Function(r)
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Clone
        row.Cells(0).Value = r
        Return row
    End Function).ToArray())
' get the sums in an IEnumerable(Of Double)
Dim sums = getSumsOfGroupsOfNRows(n)
' write into second column
For i = 1 To n
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n * i - 1).Cells(1).Value = sums(i - 1)
Next
```